# Is it possible to convert low level languages to high level ones?

Tags: compiler-theory

We know a compiler can convert high level languages to lower ones,like convert C to assembly.

But is it possible the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

To a point, yes. They are called decompilers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler

Comment: Is the decompiler possibly written in high language?

Comment: decompilers can be written in any language

Answer (score 1):

With the proper mappings of inputs to outputs ANY language can be converted to ANY OTHER language, assuming the mechanisms exist to map every feature of each.

The practicality of such tools are debatable, and the readability/maintainability of the resulting code is simply awful.

But you're talking theory, and yes it is theoretically possible to map ANY language X to ANY OTHER language Y.